# Convert array of employees to Dictionary

Tags: javascript, linq, linq.js

So I'm using the [LinqJS](https://www.npmjs.com/package/linqjs) library to currently achieve the following:

```
    var allEmployees = [
        {
            "Id": 1374,
            "FirstName": "John",
            "LastName": "Doe"
        },
        {
            "Id": 1375,
            "FirstName": "Jane",
            "LastName": "Doe"
        }
    ];
    var employeeDictionary = Enumerable.from(allEmployees).toDictionary("$.Id", "$.FirstName+' '+$.LastName").toEnumerable().toArray();
```

When serializing `employeeDictionary` to JSON, I get the following format:

```
[
  {
    "key": 1374,
    "value": "John Doe"
  },
  {
    "key": 1375,
    "value": "Jane Doe"
  }
]
```

I do not want my data in this format, I wish to have it in this format:

```
{
  "1374": "John Doe",
  "1375": "Jane Doe"
}
```

I wrote something similar in PHP using [YaLinqo](https://github.com/Athari/YaLinqo) which gives me the results I need:

```
echo json_encode(from($employees)->toDictionary('$v["Id"]', '$v["FirstName"]." ".$v["LastName"]')->toArray());
```

However, I would like to be able to achieve this in my JavaScript.

Comment: Well, `.toArray()` will give you an array back. Is there a method that returns anything else?

Comment: Well I use `toArray()` in YaLinqo and it gives me the results I'm looking for so I just tried the same thing in LinqJS.

Comment: PHP treats "arrays" as associative ones. In JS an array is strictly a numerically indexed one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, an array is strictly always numerically indexed structure. So, `.toArray` abides with that. In PHP an array is closer to what JavaScript considers plain objects.

---

If using [this LINQ JavaScript library](https://github.com/mihaifm/linq)

You can use the `.toObject` method to produce an object of your format - you need to pass in two functions - a key selector and a value selector, so the object gets built with the correct data:

```js
var allEmployees = [
    {
        "Id": 1374,
        "FirstName": "John",
        "LastName": "Doe"
    },
    {
        "Id": 1375,
        "FirstName": "Jane",
        "LastName": "Doe"
    }
];
var employeeDictionary = Enumerable.from(allEmployees)
  .toDictionary("$.Id", "$.FirstName+' '+$.LastName")
  .toEnumerable()
  .toObject(entry => entry.key, entry => entry.value);

/* output:
{
  "1374": "John Doe",
  "1375": "Jane Doe"
}
*/
```

Using destructuring, the key/value selectors can be transformed to:

```js
.toObject(({key}) => key, ({value}) => value);
```

---

If using [this library for LINQ operations](http://neue.cc/reference.htm), then you need to slightly change the syntax:

```js
var allEmployees = [
    {
        "Id": 1374,
        "FirstName": "John",
        "LastName": "Doe"
    },
    {
        "Id": 1375,
        "FirstName": "Jane",
        "LastName": "Doe"
    }
];
var employeeDictionary = Enumerable.From(allEmployees)
  .ToDictionary("$.Id", "$.FirstName+' '+$.LastName")
  .ToEnumerable()
  .ToObject("$.Key", "$.Value");

/* output:
{
  "1374": "John Doe",
  "1375": "Jane Doe"
}
*/
```

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I needed. I was looking at `.toObject` and felt like that was what I could use but wasn't sure how. Thank you!

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne hmm, I may have misled you - I was looking at a different library for LINQ in JavaScript. I'm not sure this one does the same thing. I'll try to verify if the `toObject` is correct

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne are you sure you use [the library you linked to](https://www.npmjs.com/package/linqjs)? That one doesn't have `Enumerable.from`. It's just adding the LINQ methods to the core JS array prototype. I did my test for the answer with [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/linqjs) which does provide `Enumerable.from` and the exact same API you use.

Comment: Hmm, I just googled LinqJS and that was the first one that came up. It's [this library](http://neue.cc/reference.htm)

Comment: @ThePerplexedOne yeah, I saw that one, too but it's using capitals for the method names, so `Enumerable.from` -> `Enumerable.From`. It also has a different syntax for `ToObject. I've updated my answer to address that library, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` to achieve this:

```
employeeDictionary.reduce((acc, employee) => {
  acc[employee.key] = employee.value;
  return acc
}, {})
```

Or with a shorter version by using object spread:

```
employeeDictionary.reduce((acc, employee) => ({
  ...acc,
  [employee.key]: employee.value
}), {})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are confusing an array of objects with a dictionary. I included both versions below to show the difference.

What you want to do with the data is map it, instead of reducing it.

```js
let allEmployees = [
  { "Id": 1374, "FirstName": "John", "LastName": "Doe" },
  { "Id": 1375, "FirstName": "Jane", "LastName": "Doe" }
];

let defaultOptions = {
  keyField: 'Id',
  valueFn: (emp) => `${emp['FirstName']} ${emp['LastName']}`
};

console.log('Dictionary', toDictionary(allEmployees, defaultOptions));
console.log('Pairs', toPairs(allEmployees, defaultOptions));

function toDictionary(list, options) {
  let opts = Object.assign({ keyField: 'key', valueField: 'value' }, options);
  return list.reduce((dict, item) => (Object.assign(dict, {
    [item[opts.keyField]] : opts.valueFn ? opts.valueFn(item) : item[opts.valueField]
  })), {});
}

function toPairs(list, options) {
  let opts = Object.assign({ keyField: 'key', valueField: 'value' }, options);
  return list.map((item) => ({
    key   : item[opts.keyField],
    value :  opts.valueFn ? opts.valueFn(item) : item[opts.valueField]
  }));
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

---

Here is a list wrapper class.

```js
class ListWrapper {
  constructor(list, options) {
    this.list       = list;
    this.keyField   = options.keyField   || 'key'
    this.valueField = options.valueField || 'value'
    this.valueFn    = options.valueFn               /* optional */
  }
  toPairs() {
    return this.list.map(e=>({key:e[this.keyField],value:this.valueFn?this.valueFn(e):e[this.valueField]}));
  }
  toDictionary() {
    return this.list.reduce((d,e)=>(Object.assign(d,{[e[this.keyField]]:this.valueFn?this.valueFn(e):e[this.valueField]})),{});
  }
}

let allEmployees = [
  { "Id": 1374, "FirstName": "John", "LastName": "Doe" },
  { "Id": 1375, "FirstName": "Jane", "LastName": "Doe" }
];

let listWrapper = new ListWrapper(allEmployees, {
  keyField: 'Id',
  valueFn: (emp) => `${emp['FirstName']} ${emp['LastName']}`
});

console.log('Dictionary', listWrapper.toDictionary());
console.log('Pairs', listWrapper.toPairs());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Answer (score 1):

A short linq version

```js
var allEmployees = [{ Id: 1374, FirstName: "John", LastName: "Doe" }, { Id: 1375, FirstName: "Jane", LastName: "Doe" }],
    employeeDictionary = Enumerable.From(allEmployees)
        .Select("$ => { key: $.Id, value: $.FirstName + ' ' + $.LastName }")
        .ToObject("$.key", "$.value");
    
console.log(employeeDictionary);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/linq.js/2.2.0.2/linq.js"></script>
```

A short approach with a destructuring and [`Object.fromEntries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/fromEntries).

```js
var allEmployees = [{ Id: 1374, FirstName: "John", LastName: "Doe" }, { Id: 1375, FirstName: "Jane", LastName: "Doe" }],
    employeeDictionary = Object.fromEntries(
        allEmployees.map(({ Id, FirstName, LastName }) =>
            [Id, [FirstName, LastName].join(' ')])
    );
    
console.log(employeeDictionary);
```